# Android Studio 0.8.0 with Shinobi Charts

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime, shinobi

I was trying out the sample code posted for shinobi charts on android studio 0.8.0 from

https://github.com/ShinobiControls/shinobicharts-with-android-studio

I tried to import the shinobicharts jar as an .jar library .
It compiled perfectly , but I kept getting  a runtime error and I have no clue what to do.This is the error displayed, the app never opens, just starts out with this crash

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.shinobicontrols.charts.R$styleable
        at com.shinobicontrols.charts.ct.a(SourceFile:850)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're running Proguard and it stripped out one or more needed classes.

Try turning off Proguard. If that gets past this problem, then you can turn it back on and fix its configuration file.

To fix it, you'll need to add rules to "keep" classes that it couldn't tell are needed. You can name specific classes or classname patterns. There might be a way to tell it to look at references from the library .jar to classes outside the library.

Comment: Thanks!.i ran it with proguard as false.Though now I am facing a new error on runtime.Any help would be appreciated. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load shinobicharts-android from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader....

Comment: @dante2702 hopefully http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459797/cant-load-shinobicharts-android-from-loader has a good answer to the loading problem. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992329/androidruntime-caused-by-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-load-tfp-jni#19014301 for more general info on the things needed to successfully load a native library. E.g. the `shinobicharts-android.so` file needs to be in the project's `libs/` folder (maybe it's `libshinobicharts-android.so`).